# How can I make this ruby code throw an exception and bail?

Tags: ruby, exception

I want this to throw an exception and die:

```
begin
  if meridian != "AM" and meridian != "PM"
    rescue
    puts MESSAGE
  end
end
```

I googled a lot, but nothing seems to work. I want an `if` statement to throw an exception if it fails.

Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: im terrible about using "AND" and "AN" nowadays

Comment: In ruby you throw exceptions by calling `raise`. You can check this to learn more: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html

Comment: That code will already "die" - it's invalid syntax :) `expr if cond` or `if cond [then] expr` are the valid forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked

```
      MESSAGE = "Check your formatting"
      if meridian != "AM" and  meridian  != "PM"
          abort( MESSAGE )
      end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
raise "message" unless ["AM", "PM"].include? meridian
```

Comment: More concise syntax: `%w(AM PM).include? meridian`

Comment: Make it `meridian.upcase` if you want it to be a case insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions:

```
raise 'message' unless meridian =~ /\A(a|p)m\z/i
```

This matches independently of case, and works with symbols too.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should use `fail` instead of raise, for readability matters and see link below.

```
fail "message" unless ["AM", "PM"].include? meridian
```

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#exceptions

Comment: `fail` is just an alias for `raise` but you make a good point, semantically.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `begin`/`rescue`/`end` around your `if` or replace `puts MESSAGE` with `raise "some_message_here"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `begin`/`rescue` because you aren't encountering any errors with your `if` statement. Instead:

```
 raise "message" if meridian != "AM" and meridian != "PM"
```